# Mysql gives me error while running a query

Tags: mysql

I couldn't find the problem with this query. Would you tell me what is wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE 'wish' (
 'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'title' varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 'issue_number' varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 'type_id' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 'publication_date' date DEFAULT NULL,
 'store_link' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 'notes' text DEFAULT NULL,
 'got_it' int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
 KEY 'type_id' ('type_id'),
 KEY 'got_it' ('got_it'),
 CONSTRAINT 'wish_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('type_id') REFERENCES 'type' ('id'),
 CONSTRAINT 'wish_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY ('got_it') REFERENCES 'user' ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Mysql gives this error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wish' ( 'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'title' varchar(256)' at line 1
```

**EDIT:**

When tried the query replacing back ticks with single quotes, error occurred:

```
error: #1005 - Can't create table 'comic-booksdb.wish' (errno: 150)
```

Thank you

Comment: Use backticks ` instead of single quote

Comment: In other words, replace every instance of a single quote with iether a back tick or just remove the quotes (they don't seem to be needed).  ONLY use single quotes for date and string constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks(`) instead of single quote:

```
CREATE TABLE `wish` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `issue_number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `publication_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `store_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `notes` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `got_it` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
 KEY `got_it` (`got_it`),
 CONSTRAINT `wish_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `wish_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`got_it`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Side Note:**

> Back ticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword, or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set it is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

Back ticks are necessary for situations like the following:

```
SELECT id, `my name`, `another field` , `field,with,comma`
```

**EDIT**

To avoid 'errno: 150' when dealing with integer data types, verify that the primary and foreign key columns of interest have the same integer types (size and sign, as indicated above). e.g. if primary key is 'unsigned int' and foreign key is simply 'int', then 'errno: 150' is likely.

Comment: I've tried that but new error: #1005 - Can't create table 'comic-booksdb.wish' (errno: 150)  I am using phpmyadmin